# Consistent write with DynamoDB mapper with AWS SDK =1.11.*

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDBSaveExpression has been deprecated in new version of SDK. What is the replacement of it, if I want to save a record only if it doesn't exists ?

Simple way I know is we can implement by getting the record and validating (Filter expressions), but is some other alternative available ?

Comment: I have checked it in 1.11.145 version. There is no comment that it is deprecated.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBSaveExpression.html..